# R Language: Replace text with it's own modified version

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I have CSV file with delimiter tabulation (\t symbol). And I need to convert it to CSV with delimiter comma (,). But simple replace would not work, because my text might contain comas which will break file formatting. To avoid that I need to place such a text with comma into quotes (") and only then replace all tab symbols with comma (,).

Each column captured between two symbols: ***Beginning of the file***, ***End of the file***, ***\t*** and ***\n***.

What I need is: **if the column contains comma (,) then replace it with the same text but also put it in additional quotations.** Example:

```
My text, ABC\tYour pans are gray\tGood weather\n
blue flowers\tTemp, hot toaster\tOh my Sun\n
```

So after replacement text would look like

```
"My text, ABC"\tYour pans are gray\tGood weather\n
blue flowers\t"Temp, hot toaster"\tOh my Sun\n
```

\t in is TAB symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to do this. If you read the file as tab-separated and write it as comma-separated it will automatically handle this. Try,

```
df <- read.table(text = text, sep = "\t")
write.csv(df, 'temp.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

**data**

```
text <- "My text, ABC\tYour pans are gray\tGood weather\n
         blue flowers\tTemp, hot toaster\tOh my Sun\n"
```